# Classically controlled quantum operators

Tags: programming

Does CirQ support classically controlled quantum operators where the classical values obtained by the measurement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no mechanism for performing classical feedback in cirq. It is on the roadmap. It will probably look something like `cirq.X(q)**measurement_result(key)` in the end, but for now it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for the information.